# Getting part of the value from a column title

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, document-library, if-statement

Silly question. We have a Document library and basically we are saving emails in a `*.msg` format. where the title is the subject of the email.

I would like to save part of the title as an additional column in my SharePoint list.

for instance if the user save a file and the file name is =

```
USA_SalesJanuary2021.msg
CAN_SalesReport.msg
Latin_Sales.msg
```

I Would like to see something like this:

```
Title                         Country
USA_SalesJanuary2021.msg      USA
CAN_SalesReport.msg           CAN
2021_Latin_Sales.msg          LAT
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated column and use the LEFT function to return portions of another field, take the first three letters.

```
=LEFT([file name],3)
```